# Big Query Error: Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException

Tags: google-bigquery, google-search-console, google-bigquery-storage-api

Am facing this error while using SEO-Stack.io
Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned. For more information, see [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas%22), "errors": [ { "message": "Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas", "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "quotaExceeded" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }

under stack trace:

Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper::convertToGoogleException
vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:398

return new $exception($this->getExceptionMessage($ex), $ex->getCode(), $ex);

Am trying to fetxh gsc site data over seo-stack.io